# browsing filesystem directory in jquery

Tags: jquery, browser, filesystems

I'm searching for a way (if exists) or a plugin to open a filesystem browser only using jQuery; I can't use PHP or any other server-side languages.

I mean: clicking on a link with href= "/directory/subdirectory/" I wish to open a pop-up window with the content of the directory and download a file in it.
I hope I was clear. :)

Any help will be strongly apreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: To be clear, this is the filesystem on the server? Or the users local?

Comment: The browser can't actually see the directory unless the server has directory browsing turned on. At that point, I'm pretty sure all that you can do is perform an ajax request getting the html content returned for directory browsing, then parsing that html content to get the links to files/directories within the directory. I don't know if that is even possible, I haven't tried.

Comment: @skylar: I'm referring to the users local filesystem.

Comment: the browser has no access the the local filesystem without using things like active-x objects or flash/silverlight